# How to check if page exists?

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one check to see if a remote file exists using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php)
>   [How to check if a webpage exists. jQuery and/or PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536118/how-to-check-if-a-webpage-exists-jquery-and-or-php)

How can I check if a page from a different domain exists using php or javascript?

I've tried this:

```
function getURL($url, $includeContents = false)
{
  if($includeContents)
    return @file_get_contents($url);

  return (@file_get_contents($url, null, null, 0, 0) !== false);
}


$test = getURL("http://www.google.com");

echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('$test');</script>";
```

but it doesn't work.

If I use a local url it works.

---

How to solve this?

Comment: or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722613/check-if-a-remote-page-exists-using-php.

Comment: @matino, I've tried what was there but only worked in the same domain.

Comment: fyi, the `language` attribute of `<script> is obsolute. you can use `type="text/javascript"` instead but that's the default anyway

Comment: is your php config on `safe mode`?

Comment: c'mon 6,272 rep, suppressing errors `@` and then saying **it dont work** classic

Comment: Exactly what doesn't work? Running your code I get this result: `<script language='javascript'>alert('1');</script>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read content from other pages i`m using CURL and do it like that

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
$page_content = curl_exec($ch);   
curl_close($ch); 
if ($page_content != "false") {
 // do something with content  
} else {
  // this page is not available
}
```

Comment: Or just check the headers like in the mentioned dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981954/how-can-one-check-to-see-if-a-remote-file-exists-using-php `$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);`

Answer (score 2):

it can not be done by pure Javascript.

In PHP, request the page and check if it has **`200` http response code**. This result can be returned to JS via ajax call so that JavaScript can show a message or do other action accordingly.

Comment: maybe with ajax. php handling the task returning response.